# Issues with event bubbling when deleting a row in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a row of user input transactions. On the index page (list) of transactions I want to allow the user to hover over the table row and click it to open/edit. I do this with Javascript (ofcourse :)

```
$('.transaction-row').on('click', function(e) {
  window.location.href = '/transactions/'+$(this).data('id')+'/edit';
  return false;
});
```

This works fine and when the user clicks the row, it takes them to the edit page.

The problem is that I also have a delete button within the row, which I want to keep there.

```
<%= link_to transaction, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
  Delete
<% end %>
```

So, when I click on this it bubbles up to the row and opens the edit page instead. I thought I'd handle it with Javascript and use "return false" to prevent the bubbling, but I can't send a "DELETE" HTTP action - or at least I don't know how to.

I tried this using jQuery:

```
$('.delete-transaction-link').on('click', function(e) {
  if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    var url = '/transactions/'+$(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "DELETE"
    }).done(function(){
        window.reload();
    });
  }
  return false;
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
});
```

..but the browser gives me some warning alert telling me "This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend the form data you have typed to the new location?" - not ideal

Can anyone give me any idea how I could do this. I'm not so familiar with putting HTTP action/methods (e.g. DELETE) into a link, or rails for that matter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is $(this).data('id') giving you correct id? I am not sure but I believe $(this).data('id') should be replaced with $(this).attr('id')?

Answer (score 1):

Your `preventDefault()` is never called since it's placed after a return statement. Switch those two lines, and the event should be caught before it reaches the handler of your row.

```
$('.delete-transaction-link').on('click', function(e) {
  // ... your ajax stuff

  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
  return false;
});
```

However, the main point of ajax is that the page doesn't reload completely. In your case, you are reloading the page when the delete action completes. Instead you could just normally link to this action and then redirect back to the list page from the Rails controller without using ajax at all.

If you still want to use ajax though, you should rather delete (or at least hide and disable) the deleted row using Javascript.

Comment: `e.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
return false;`